# How can I improve or re-write this code and make it efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have had to repeat myself to enable the "Enter" key functionality, but it works. I was considering disabling it but taking user experience into consideration I want to enable it. Currently working on a simple to do list application powered by JQuery and JQuery UI. Below is the extract from the code.

```
var $inputButtonHolder = $('.input-button-holder')
var $userListContainer = $('.user-items-container');//Grab main container which is hard coded
var $sortDivContainer = $('<div class="sorter-container"></div>');
//Event handler attached to button element
$('#add-button').on('click', function(){
    var $userInput = $('#add-to-do').val();//Get User Input
    function addUserItem(){
        var $spanElem = $('<span class="user-input">').append($userInput);//Dynamically generating a span element
        var $listOptions = $('<a href="#" class="delete-list">Delete</a>');//Dynamically generating a tag element
        //Div element to hold child elements span and a tag - also dynamically generated
        var $newDivElem = $('<div>',{
            "class": 'user-item',
        }).append($spanElem);
        //Checkboxes also dynamically generated and appended to newDivElem
        var $checkBoxes = $('<input>', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'}).appendTo($newDivElem);
        $listOptions.appendTo($newDivElem);//append delete option to user list item
        $userListContainer.append($sortDivContainer);//Append user item div which will enable sorting using JQ UI
        $sortDivContainer.append($newDivElem); //Here we append user input
        $('#add-to-do').val('');
        $('.warning-message').hide();   
    };
    //pu
    if($userInput==''){
        $('.warning-message').fadeIn();
    }else {
        addUserItem();
    };
});
//when user presses the enter key after input
$('#add-to-do').on('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var $userInput = $('#add-to-do').val();//Get User Input
        function addUserItem(){
            var $spanElem = $('<span class="user-input">').append($userInput);//Dynamically generating a span element
            var $listOptions = $('<a href="#" class="delete-list">Delete</a>');//Dynamically generating a tag element
            //Div element to hold child elements span and a tag - also dynamically generated
            var $newDivElem = $('<div>',{
                "class": 'user-item',
            }).append($spanElem);
            //Checkboxes also dynamically generated and appended to newDivElem
            var $checkBoxes = $('<input>', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'}).appendTo($newDivElem);
            $listOptions.appendTo($newDivElem);//append delete option to user list item
            $userListContainer.append($sortDivContainer);//Append user item div which will enable sorting using JQ UI
            $sortDivContainer.append($newDivElem); //Here we append user input
            $('#add-to-do').val('');
            $('.warning-message').hide();   
        };
        if($userInput==''){
            $('.warning-message').fadeIn();
        }else {
            addUserItem();
        };
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fits better on another Stack Exchange network http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

First step is extracting the inner function and then reusing it.

```
var $inputButtonHolder = $('.input-button-holder')
var $userListContainer = $('.user-items-container'); //Grab main container which is hard coded
var $sortDivContainer = $('<div class="sorter-container"></div>');
var $addButton = $('#add-button');
var $addToDoButton = $('#add-to-do');
var $warning = $('.warning-message');
//Event handler attached to button element
$addButton.on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this); 
  var $userInput = $this.val(); //Get User Input
  checkUserInput($userInput);
});
//when user presses the enter key after input
$addToDoButton.on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $userInput = $this.val(); //Get User Input
    checkUserInput($userInput);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

function checkUserInput($userInput) {
    if (!$userInput) {
      $warning.fadeIn();
    } else {
      addUserItem($userInput);
    };
}

function addUserItem($userInput) {
    var $spanElem = $('<span>', {"class": 'user-input'}).append($userInput); //Dynamically generating a span element
    var $listOptions = $('<a href="#" class="delete-list">Delete</a>'); //Dynamically generating a tag element
    //Div element to hold child elements span and a tag - also dynamically generated
    var $newDivElem = $('<div>', {
      "class": 'user-item',
    }).append($spanElem);
    //Checkboxes also dynamically generated and appended to newDivElem
    var $checkBoxes = $('<input>', {
      type: 'checkbox',
      id: 'cb'
    }).appendTo($newDivElem);
    $listOptions.appendTo($newDivElem); //append delete option to user list item
    $userListContainer.append($sortDivContainer); //Append user item div which will enable sorting using JQ UI
    $sortDivContainer.append($newDivElem); //Here we append user input
    $addToDoButton.val('');
    $warning.hide();
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you have the addUserItem() function twice. You could make it a 'public' function and then just call it. No need to have all of that code typed twice.